# Orchard CMS how to access a modules controller that returns a ContentResult

Tags: jquery, ajax, module, controller, orchardcms

I'm new to Orchard CMS and how to extend it. I can't find a descriptive answer on how to call an action from a controller that's located in a module? The action returns a ContentResult with the type being plain text. I want to access it in an jQuery AJAX call. I'm a novice at Orchard CMS. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Return a `JsonResult` from your controller action. Use `Url.Action` to get the URL of your action.